# Problem With MaskedTextBoc

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mask

I want to do in silverlight following thing:
in TextBox I wan to mask: When in put string is for example "25" it should display as "00000025"

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Silverlight Super TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/STextBox.aspx) on CodeProject.com (has a lot more in addition to the Mask)

Hope this helps :)